# Modifying margins programmatically for view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to modify the margins of a view.

If I get the margins for the view on onCreateView for the fragment (just after inflating the layout), I get the values defined on the xml. If I change the margin values to 0, I get the desired results.

This is how the fragment looks before making any changes:
[image]

If remove the margins on onCreateView, I get this (which is what I want):
[image]

The problem I am having is that if I get the margins for that same view, but after the onCreateView has been called, the margins will show as 0, and if I try to remove the margins by adding a negative margin, I get this (the bar just gets smaller):

[image]

This is my search_bar_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <!--Some elements -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And then on code I get the LinearLayout as the view, and update the margins. This is what I do on onCreateView (which achieves the desired result):

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_bar_layout, container, false);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
Log.d("MARGIN", String.valueOf(lp.leftMargin)); // is 24
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And this is what I run after onCreateView (does not removes margin, makes bar smaller):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
Log.d("MARGIN", String.valueOf(lp.leftMargin)); // is 0
lp.setMargins(-24, -24, -24, -24); // Changing to negative value because current value is 0
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Why does this happen? How can I modify the margins after onCreateView has been called?

Comment: Could you add some code for both examples (i.e., how are you setting/retrieving margins onCreateView and later)?

Comment: @user1845791 Is there some reason you're not setting the margin in XML?

Comment: I want it to change when the user focuses on the input.